# Use subselect in insert to temp-table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert a subselect in one insert to a temp table. Thing is I want to use one insert, in this insert I want to insert my sub-select to the third column of the temp table. I know that I only have 2 parameters in the first select, the trick is the third. How do I get into col 3 by using 1 insert and 1 subselect. I get the error message

```
Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Stored_Procedure, 
Line 24 The select list for the INSERT statement 
contains fewer items than the insert list. The         
number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
```

This is my code.

```
insert into #Temp (Col01,Col02,Col03)
select X, Y from Table
where Y = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,-0,GETDATE()),112)
and Z = '8:00' (Select X from Table 
where Datum = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,-0,GETDATE()),112)
and Z = '17:00')
```

Comment: Well, your `#Temp` table has three columns, but you are trying to insert only two values, X and Y. Where is your subselect?

Comment: no shit? @mario look at the description. I'm trying to use sub-select for third column....

Comment: Easy with the attitude. What I'm trying to say is that you don't have a subselect on a third column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it instead.. if you want to use 1 insert with subselect you should do it this way.

```
    insert into #ExcelPrint (Col01,Col02,Col03)
    select 
    Z,
    X as X_8, 
    (Select Kl_17.X from Table as Kl_17
    where Kl_17.Y = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,-0,GETDATE()),112)
    and Kl_17.X = '17:00' 
    and Kl_17.Z = Table.Z) 
    as X_17
    from Table
    where Datum = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,-0,GETDATE()),112)
    and Z = '8:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

number of parameter does not match to no of value

insert into #Temp (Col01,Col02,Col03)--parameters 3
select X, Y --values 2

```
  insert into #Temp (Col01,Col02,Col03)
  select X, Y , Z from Table
  where Y = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,-0,GETDATE()),112)
  and Z = '8:00' (Select X from Table 
  where Datum = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,-0,GETDATE()),112)
 and Z = '17:00')
```